# fitting movie clip to 4 coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, transformation, movieclip, coordinate-transformation

im very nex to action script but i've got a problem with an movieclip.

i've got 4 coodinates an need to fit a fit movie clip to them, so each corner of the movieclips is on one coordinate.

The only thing i could find it tranforming it with a matrix and angles (see example), but these cant be the best solution for my problem to calculate all the angles etc.

```
var degX:Number = 0;
var degY:Number = 0.3;

//Get the transform matrix for the object to skew
var m:Matrix = bild.transform.matrix;
m.b = Math.tan(degY *(Math.PI/180));
m.c = Math.tan(degX *(Math.PI/180));

//Apply the matrix to the transform object
var t:Transform = new Transform(bild);
t.matrix = m;

//Apply the skew
bild.transform = t;
```

i hope you understand my problem and know a solution for it.

i've tried distord image as it seems to do exaclty what it need but i cant get it so show my image. the coordinates work, if i un comment the commented part i see white retangles exaclty where they should be, but they don't get deleted on update, i hope you cann help my. here is my code:

```
var PointUR:Point = new Point();
PointUR.x = values1[0];
PointUR.y = values1[1];

var PointUL:Point = new Point();
PointUL.x = values2[0];
PointUL.y = values2[1];

var PointBR:Point = new Point();
PointBR.x = values3[0];
PointBR.y = values3[1];

var PointBL:Point = new Point();
PointBL.x = values4[0];
PointBL.y = values4[1];


[Embed(source='MyImage.jpg')]
var MyImage:Class;
var shape:Shape = new Shape();
var bitmap:Bitmap = new MyImage();
var showGrid:Boolean = true;
var myColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
/*myColorTransform.color = 0xFFFFFF;
shape.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
shape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
addChild(shape);*/
var distortion:DistortImage = new DistortImage(267, 400, 3, 3);
if (showGrid){
            shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x00FF00);
}    
distortion.setTransform(shape.graphics, 
                        bitmap.bitmapData, 
                        PointUR, 
                        PointUL, 
                        PointBR, 
                        PointBL);
```

Comment: do the 4 points form a rectangle, parallelogram or trapezoid?

Comment: they are trapezoid but they changeover the time so they could be a prallelgram on some time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming a movieClip or Sprite into a trapezoid using the matrix is impossible in as3.  Check out [this link](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) that explains the extent of possibilities

in short:

[image]

The way this has been achieved is by breaking up the DisplayObject into smaller triangles, and applying different translation matrix to each. The end result makes the triangles pop out a bit, but if you increase the number of triangles, this effect gets diminished.

here's a [link](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) for a blog with demo and source

It is much easier to do this with 3d classes or Mathieu Badimon's [five3d](http://five3d.mathieu-badimon.com/), the distortion part anyway, I'm not sure how you would do it to match a set of control points.

Comment: thank you, for your post this seems to be exactly what i need but i cant get it to work, please take a look at my code i added above.